# Captioning a pandas dataframe from sqlite and outputing with a web browser with Python

Tags: python, html, pandas, sqlite

I have a function in my Python script which picks values from an sqlite database into a pandas (pd) dataframe to be outputted in a web browser.

I want the outputted table to display a caption for the table in the browser.

The caption should look like

> "This table shows the rate of collections for the month of month.get()" in the year year.get()

My function code:

```
def all_collectors_info():
      Database()
      a = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `collectors` WHERE Month = ? AND Year = ?", (MONTH.get(), YEAR.get(),))
      fetch = cursor.fetchall()
      z = [x for x in fetch]
      cols = [column[0] for column in a.description]
      pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
      pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
      df= pd.DataFrame.from_records(data = fetch, columns = cols, index = list(range(1, (len(z)+1))))

      html = df.to_html()
      text_file = open("index.html", "w")
      text_file.write(html)
      text_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct option to add `<caption>` tag to table from pandas, but you can just append heading(<h#> tag) like

```py
heading_template = '<h3>This table shows the rate of collections for the month of {month} in the year {year}</h3>\n'
html = df.to_html()
html = heading_template.format(month=MONTH.get(), year=YEAR.get()) + html
```

So your final function would be

```py
def all_collectors_info():
      Database()
      a = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `collectors` WHERE Month = ? AND Year = ?", (MONTH.get(), YEAR.get(),))
      fetch = cursor.fetchall()
      z = [x for x in fetch]
      cols = [column[0] for column in a.description]
      pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
      pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
      df= pd.DataFrame.from_records(data = fetch, columns = cols, index = list(range(1, (len(z)+1))))

      heading_template = '<h3>This table shows the rate of collections for the month of {month} in the year {year}</h3>\n'
      html = df.to_html()
      html = heading_template.format(month=MONTH.get(), year=YEAR.get()) + html
      text_file = open("index.html", "w")
      text_file.write(html)
      text_file.close()
```